# Does differentiability implies local continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a mapping that is differentiable at $t_0\in (-1,1)$. Can we deduce that there is a neighberhood $W$ of $t_0$ such that $f$ is continuous over $W$ ?